# Change Add to Cart Button to View Cart Button after click in Woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I have a Wordpress website. I am using the Storefront theme for WooCommerce. I have ajax add to cart buttons enabled. When an Add to Cart button is clicked and a product is successfully added to the cart I would like the button to change to a View Cart button (change the text to "View Cart", and link to the cart). If possible I would also like to style the button differently to differentiate it from the standard add to cart button. What would the php code look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Woocommerce by default, when you click on "add to cart" button another button already appears **on the right side with "View Cart"**:

[image]

This is already done by a woocommerce jQuery script, that adds after Add to cart button a "View cart" button  linked to the cart page…

You can hide the "add to cart" button if you like as when clicked an additional class **`"added"`** appears in it (see the generated code below):

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="/shop/?add-to-cart=741" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="741" data-product_sku="WN001-1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart added">Add to cart</a>
```

So with CSS you can use `display:none;` on it **and only keep "View Cart"** …

```css
.ajax_add_to_cart.added {
    display:none !important;
}
```

[image]

Then is easy to re-style that "view cart" button (linked to the cart page):

```
a.added_to_cart.wc-forward {
    background-color: #8c8c8c !important;
    color: white !important;
    min: .618em 2.4em !important;
}
a.added_to_cart.wc-forward:after {
    content: inherit; !important;
}
```

[image]

So you don't need any code, just some CSS…

Comment: thank you! is there any way to style/edit it thru template files?  override in functions.php?