# Change Add To Cart Button Text on ajax Added To Cart in Woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am trying to change the **Add To Cart** text to say **Add Another?** once the button has been clicked and the product added to the cart. Items are being added to the cart via AJAX on the Archive page.

So far I am able to change the text on a *static basis* with the code below, but can't seem to figure out how to do this when the item is added to the cart.

I have researched and found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49583367/change-add-to-cart-button-to-view-cart-button-after-click-in-woocommerce), but this is slightly different as I am intentionally hiding the View Cart button as I don't want the user to be able to view the cart directly.

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'wh_archive_custom_cart_button_text');   // 2.1 +

    function wh_archive_custom_cart_button_text()
    {
//IF FUNCTION HERE?
        return __('Add To Box', 'woocommerce');
    }
```

Comment: In the linked answer, you will find the convenient jQuery script to get what you are expecting.

Comment: Ah perfect. Will vote up - didn't see that!